# The mysql extension is deprecated in Codeigniter 2.2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

with my Codeigniter 2.2 version and 
PHP Version 5.5.16-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
and
Mysql Client API version 5.5.38 
I get error :

```
Message: mysql_insert_id(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
```

But in my  application/config/database.php 'mysqli' is set :

```
  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
  $db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'bp_';
  $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
  $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
  $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

What is wrong ? Which is valid format for pdo and which packet have I to install from my

```
# apt-cache search pdo
ifupdown - high level tools to configure network interfaces
php5-mysql - MySQL module for php5
php5-odbc - ODBC module for php5
php5-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for php5
php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5
gap-gapdoc - GAPDoc meta package for GAP documentation
guessnet - Guess which LAN a network device is connected to
ifupdown-extra - Network scripts for ifupdown
ifupdown-multi - multiple default gateway support for ifupdown
ifupdown-scripts-zg2 - Zugschlus' interface scripts for ifupdown's manual method
irssi-scripts - collection of scripts for irssi
libjnlp-servlet-java - simple and convenient packaging format for JNLP applications
mediawiki-extensions-base - Extensions for MediaWiki -- Base package
netscript-2.4 - Linux 2.4/2.6 router/firewall/VM host network config. system.
netscript-2.4-upstart - Linux 2.4/2.6 router/firewall/VM host network config. system.
pd-pdogg - collection of Ogg/Vorbis objects for Pd
php-apigen - API documentation generator for PHP 5.3+
php-db - PHP PEAR Database Abstraction Layer
php-mdb2 - merge of the PEAR DB and Metabase php database abstraction layers
php-phpdocx - dynamical generation of .docx files
php-structures-datagrid - Render a data table with automatic pagination and sorting
php5-mysqlnd - MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
php5-mysqlnd-ms - MySQL replication and load balancing module for PHP
php5-sybase - Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
python-setupdocs - setuptools plugin that automates building of docs from reST source
python-sphinxcontrib-httpdomain - Sphinx domain for HTTP APIs
python-sphinxcontrib.phpdomain - Sphinx "phpdomain" extension
sheepdog - distributed storage system for QEMU
```

Comment: It might be possible some where in your code "mysql_insert_id()" is written statically so search for it and change it to "mysqli_insert_id()"

Comment: Yes, seems mysqli_insert_id() is decision, but it has required $link parameter? How can I get it in model, as I do not create mysql link manually ?